# Fast-csv writing all in a single line. Need multiple line output

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, export-to-csv

I have an API call that loops into JSON and outputs through fast-csv.  However, it’s outputing all into a single line in the csv file.   Is there a way for it to write in multiple lines?

```
axios.get(url+'term='+orgName +'&location='+city + state + zipCode,{
            headers: {
                Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
            }
        })
        /*If results are less than 1, moves on to fetchWhitePages API, ELSE, passes in the data*/
            .then(res => {
                if(Array.isArray(res.data.businesses) && res.data.businesses.length <= 0){
                   return fetchWhitePages(data);
                }else{
                    console.log('RUNNING YELPAPI');
                    /*For loop to get JSON objects within YelpAPI */

                    for(let i =0; i < res.data.businesses.length; i++ ){

                        churchName.push(res.data.businesses[i].name + '\n\r');
                        churchAddress.push(res.data.businesses[i].location.display_address + '\n\r');
                        churchPhone.push(res.data.businesses[i].phone + '\n\r' );

                        writeStream()




const churchName = [];
const churchAddress = [];
const churchPhone = [];

function writeStream (){
    fast
        .writeToPath("my.csv", [
                {name: churchName, address: churchAddress, phone: churchPhone}
        ], {
            headers: true,
            transform: function(row){
                return {
                    Name: row.name,
                    Address: row.address,
                    Phone: row.phone
                };
            }
        })
        .on("finish", function(){
            console.log("done!");
        });
}
```

Comment: Not sure if its relevant for answering but would you mind posting the entire .then block?

Comment: I added the write stream method that i am using.

Comment: @Christoph see the addition.  It all prints in one line.  What i am trying to do is have three columns with name, address, phone.   and each line print right below it accordingly.

Comment: The .then block is still incomplete, code example looks very ugly, please fix. I don't have the time to type up a well-written solution right now but there are actually two problems in your code. 1) fast-csv.writeToPath probably overwrites the file with every call, couldn't confirm from the docs though, 2) you need to pass an array of church objects, each with name, address and phone. You are passing one object with three properties, each containing a big array. So this single object gets written to one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things need to be fixed in your code:

1. Only call writeToPath once, after the for loop.
2. Construct an array of church objects, each representing exactly one church.

And this is how this could look like:

```
axios.get(url + 'term=' + orgName + '&location=' + city + state + zipCode, {
        headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    })
    /*If results are less than 1, moves on to fetchWhitePages API, ELSE, passes in the data*/
    .then(res => {
        if (Array.isArray(res.data.businesses) && res.data.businesses.length <= 0) {
           return fetchWhitePages(data);
        } else {
            console.log('RUNNING YELPAPI');
            /*For loop to get JSON objects within YelpAPI */

            const churches = [];
            for(let i =0; i < res.data.businesses.length; i++ ){

                churches.push({
                    name: res.data.businesses[i].name + '\n\r';                 
                    address: res.data.businesses[i].location.display_address + '\n\r';
                    phone: res.data.businesses[i].phone + '\n\r';
                });

            }

            writeFile(churches);
       }
  });


function writeStream (churches) {
    fast.writeToPath("my.csv", churches, {
        headers: true,
        transform: function(row){
            // you could eliminate this block by changing the property names in the church objects
            return {
                Name: row.name,
                Address: row.address,
                Phone: row.phone
            };
        }
    })
    .on("finish", function(){
        console.log("done!");
    });
}
```

If this solves your problem, please don't forget to mark this as the answer.

Comment: Thank you, should the   “const churches = {}”  be that instead of [] like you have it? Or did I miss something?

Comment: No, it should be []. It's an empty array to which you append all those temp church objects. {} would be a regular object, and appending objects to an object won't make much sense (even though with Javascript it actually may even work).